# NodeJs Google Speech API Followed Streaming recognition

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-speech

I am working on a project that will need to use streaming recognition. I want to make it work with NodeJs, like [here](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/streaming-recognize#speech-streaming-mic-recognize-nodejs). It works fine but as the documentation says, it stops after roughtly 60 seconds.

What I want is to restart the recording and the recognition right after this error happens, as my text might take more than one min.

I tried to close the record when I receive an error in my recognition:

```
const record = require('node-record-lpcm16');
const unirest = require('unirest');

const speech = require('@google-cloud/speech');

const client = new speech.SpeechClient();
const request = {
    config: {
        encoding: encoding,
        sampleRateHertz: sampleRateHertz,
        languageCode: languageCode
    },
    interimResults: false
};
const recognizeStream = client
    .streamingRecognize(request)
    .on('error', error => {
        console.log("Timeout...");
        console.error(error);
        console.log("Closing record");
        return record.stop();
    })
    .on('data', (data) => {
        //Process data
    });
```

And restarting the recording when it is ended:

```
record
    .start({
        sampleRateHertz: sampleRateHertz,
        threshold: 0,
        verbose: false,
        recordProgram: 'rec',
        silence: '1.0'
    })
    .on('error', console.error)
    .on('end', data => {
        record.start({
        sampleRateHertz: sampleRateHertz,
        threshold: 0,
        verbose: false,
        recordProgram: 'rec',
        silence: '1.0'
    }).pipe(recognizeStream);
    })
    .pipe(recognizeStream);
```

As a noobie in NodeJs it is the only solution I thought of but it doesn't work. The recording starts again correctly but the recognition doesn't as it doesn't transcript anything after it has been closed.

Any idea on how to perform a recognition for more than one minute with streaming recognition? I'd like something similar to what can be done in Python [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/speech-continuous/speech/cloud-client/transcribe_streaming_indefinite.py)

Comment: I am not a node.js expert, but I wanted to point out that Speech API docs mention another [limit for streaming requests](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/quotas#content), that is around 5 minutes.

Comment: You're right they changed the value in the document since then, I'll have to check again